# Can’t delete a custom post in front end with custom role

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

forks!

Well, I’m developing a plugin with a custom post type and I need create a front end page with form who allow a custom role (create by third part plugin) create and delete my custom post. But, I receive a not allow delete error alert.

Register CPT.

```
register_post_type('zonas',
    array(
        'labels'      => array(
            'name'          => __('Zonas de treino'),
            'singular_name' => __('Zona de treino'),
    ),
        'public'      => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite'     => ["slug" => "zonas"],
        "menu_position" => 120, 
        'capabilities' => array(
            'edit_post'          => 'edit_zonas', 
            'read_post'          => 'read_zonas', 
            'delete_post'        => 'delete_zonas', 
            'edit_posts'         => 'edit_zonas', 
            'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_others_zonas', 
            'publish_posts'      => 'publish_zonas',       
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_zonas', 
            'create_posts'       => 'edit_zonas', 
            'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_zonas'
        ),
        "menu_icon"     => "dashicons-clock",
        "supports"      => [
            "title"
        ]
    )
);
```

Function to generate delete link (works with administrator role)

```
function wp_delete_post_link($link = 'Excluir', $before = '', $after = '', $post) {    
    $link = "".$link."";
    echo $before . $link . $after;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at line 63 of the code 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/

If you don't provide a specific post, it is not allowed.

Your code is mixing meta capabilities with primitive capabilities. (yours are all plural or primitive)

> "Meta" capabilities, e.g. 'edit_post', 'edit_user', etc., are capabilities used by map_meta_cap() to map to other "primitive" capabilities, e.g. 'edit_posts', 'edit_others_posts', etc.

The meta capability uses the object to make it into a primitive, but if you don't pass it in the link, how can it be used?